# C++ 307 Errors when trying to include winhttp.h in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, winhttp

I have a big big problem. I'm trying to use WinHttp to download file with C++ and I'm using Visual Studio 2010 in order to do this thing.

My problem is that the program is not compiling because are generated 307 errors, all refering to `winhttp.h`.  I mention that I have included that file. What could be the problem? Thanks!

There are some:

```
------ Build started: Project: a, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------

  b. Cpp

  a. Cpp

c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(50): error C2146: 
Syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'HINTERNET'

c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(50): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(50): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(51): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'

c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(51): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(51): error C2378: 'HINTERNET': redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef

          c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(50): see declaration of 'HINTERNET'


c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(51): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(53): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'INTERNET_PORT'

c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(53): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(53): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(54): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(54): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(54): error C2378: 'INTERNET_PORT': redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef
          c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(53): see declaration of 'INTERNET_PORT'
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(54): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(95): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'dwResult'
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(95): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(95): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(96): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'dwError'
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(96): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(96): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(107): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'dwMajorVersion'
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(107): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(107): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(108): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'dwMinorVersion'
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(108): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(108): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(144): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'dwStructSize'
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(144): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(144): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c: \program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winhttp. H(145): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'lpszScheme'
```

---

Now I have another problem. This is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
    LPBYTE pszOutBuffer;
    BOOL bResults = FALSE;
    HINTERNET hSession = NULL, hConnect = NULL, hRequest = NULL;

// Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
hSession = WinHttpOpen( L"Internet Explorer example", 
    WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, 
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0 );

// Specify an HTTP server.
if( hSession )
    hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, L"www.my-new-gadget.com",
    INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0 );

// Create an HTTP request handle.
if( hConnect )
    hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"GET", L"index.php",
    NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
    NULL, NULL);

// Send a request.
if( hRequest )
    bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest,
    WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0,
    WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 
    0, 0 );

// End the request.
if( bResults )
    bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL );

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("D:\\index.php", GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (bResults)
{
    do     
    {        
        // Check for available data.        
        dwSize = 0;        
        if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable( hRequest, &dwSize))
            printf( "Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n", GetLastError());        
        // Allocate space for the buffer.        
        pszOutBuffer = new byte[dwSize+1];        
        if (!pszOutBuffer)        
        {            
            printf("Out of memory\n");            
            dwSize=0;        
        }        
        else        
        {            
            // Read the Data.            
            ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize+1);            
            if (!WinHttpReadData( hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer, dwSize, &dwDownloaded))                
            {                
                printf( "Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError());                
            }            
            else                
            {                        
                //printf("%s", pszOutBuffer); 
                DWORD wmWritten;
                bool fr = WriteFile(hFile, pszOutBuffer, dwSize, &wmWritten, NULL);
                int n = GetLastError();              
            }            
            // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.            
            delete [] pszOutBuffer;        
        }    
    } while (dwSize>0);
}

CloseHandle(hFile);
// Report any errors.
if (!bResults)    
    printf("Error %d has occurred.\n",GetLastError());
// Close any open handles.
if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);

return 0;
}
```

---

And the output is:

```
------ Build started: Project: a, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  a.cpp
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\a\a\a.cpp(73): warning C4800: 'BOOL' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
a.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WinHttpCloseHandle@4 referenced in function _main
a.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WinHttpReadData@16 referenced in function _main
a.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WinHttpQueryDataAvailable@8 referenced in function _main
a.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WinHttpReceiveResponse@8 referenced in function _main
a.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WinHttpSendRequest@28 referenced in function _main
a.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WinHttpOpenRequest@28 referenced in function _main
a.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WinHttpConnect@16 referenced in function _main
a.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WinHttpOpen@20 referenced in function _main
MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\a\Debug\a.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What could now be the problem? I'm trying for 2 days to make a piece of program to download a file from a given URL. It's driving me crazy! Please help me!

Comment: post some code.. also give us some of the errors, I guess most of them are similar.

Comment: Could you post the whole error message?

Comment: Post the whole `#include` block.  Possibly some dependencies are missing (like `windows.h` or something).

Comment: Yes detunized, that was the problem. I've put the windows.h header after winhttp.h. :(

Comment: For second question see [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588420/c-compile-problem-with-winhttp-windows-sdk).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `#include <windows.h>` before `#include <winhttp.h>`.