# Qt <winInet.h> outputs many C4430 & C2146 Errors on build

Tags: c++, windows, qt, header-files

[List of Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOPqj.png)

I think I have included the library for winInet.h in the QT Project file here:

project.pro

```
QT += qml quick network

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp \
xmap.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

LIBS += -lwininet
```

Everytime I try qmake and build the header file shows many syntax errors and I'm curious if its because I'm wrong in my qt project file syntax.

xmap.h

```
#ifndef XMAP_H
#define XMAP_H

#include <iostream>
#include <WinInet.h>    // <--- ISSUE
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>

class xmap
{
public:
xmap();

// test connection to websites for data
 int CheckConnection(int connection = 0);

// pull data from online sources to be evaluated by the model
void RequestAndSaveData(std::string filename);


};

#endif // XMAP_H
```

Comment: @eyllanesc: No need to dwell on standard OS libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the same as [C++ 307 Errors when trying to include winhttp.h in visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798798/c-307-errors-when-trying-to-include-winhttp-h-in-visual-studio-2010), except that was using WinHttp instead of WinInet.

Still, same solution: include `<Windows.h>` *before* `<WinInet.h>`.